# Similarity between future perfect and future perfect continuous

Tags: tenses, future, future-perfect, perfect-continuous, shorthand

I had an assignment given before some days. I tried to do it and got some answers right, but it was not satisfactory. Can you tell me the similarity between future perfect and future perfect continuous? It is preferable if you give me some examples.

Comment: Do you mean similarity (what makes them alike) or difference (what makes them different)?

Answer (score 1):

Like all the perfect and perfect continuous tenses, the prefect continuous refers to an action which will be taking place over a specific time in the future and talked about the time after that period.

"I will have finished my degree in 2022" means as of 2022 I will have a degree (I am talking about it now but refering to the duration from the future point of view. 
on the other hand if I would like to tlak about an action for a fixed period of time that has been continuously taking place, I should use future perfect continuous, such as "I will have been going to my college for the next four years".

I will have finished 4 books by this Christmas.
I will have been reading 4 books by this Christmas.

The difference is on the point of view of the same actions (finishing point or the contunuity of the action).

Hope it helps.

best
Travis

Answer (score 0):

The similarity is that both tenses are used to talk about actions or states that will be in progress at a particular time in the future.
For example:
‘It’s likely that by 2100, average world temperatures will have risen /or: will have been rising.
The difference is that only the Future Perfect Tense is used to talk aboutactions or states that will be finished at a particular time in the future. 
Compare with the previous sentence:  ‘It’s likely that by 2100, average world temperatures will have risen by two to five degrees.
(From Macmillan's Dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

[Future Perfect Continuous](https://english.naveedplace.com/future-perfect-continuous) - Definition:
"It emphasizes the duration of action which will be in Progress before another Action in the Future"

[Future Perfect](https://english.naveedplace.com/future-perfect)

The Formal - Definition / Usage Is - "An Action Which Will Be Completed By A Certain Time In Future"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with the sites you link to? If so, please make that clear.